# Placement of class definition and prototype

Tags: c++, class

When I create a function, I can put the code for it after main if I put the prototype above main.  For example,

```
int myFunction(int a)
{
return(a); 
}
```

would have the prototype..

```
int myFunction(int a);
```

above main.

However, I have not been able to get this to work for a class definition.

If I put …

```
class myClass
{
…
};
```

below main,

I get an error if I put

```
class myClass;
```

above main. The error occurs where the class is used within main, and the error is "unknown type name."  That's with the c++ compiler that is part of Xcode.

What kind of prototype should I enter above main if the class definition is below main?

Comment: You need a full class declaration rather than a forward declaration in this case. The class function definitions still can be made after `main()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call a function and the definition is not available, the compiler doesn't have to know the contents in order to continue evaluating the rest of the code (eg: stack usage at the call site). It only needs to know the function's signature to ensure the correct parameters are going to be passed into the function. The linker will hook up the actual address for the function call after the compiler is done.

However when you are using a class it has to know about the details of it - not just that it exists - because it'll need to ensure proper layout on the stack, what parameters are required for the constructor, etc.

The details of the class' functions are of course like regular functions - it just needs the signature to work with - they can be defined later.

Answer (score 4):

A function in C++ is like a black box to its callers; they just need to know what to pass it and what it returns in order to use it.

Classes, on the other hand, cannot be used in this way, because the compiler needs to know how much space to allocate for them, what the types of their members are, etc.

Answer (score 2):

A class definition is a little different because it can contain member function prototypes and definitions.

If your class definition (usually placed in a `.h` file) is in the same file, then you'll want it to be above your `main()`. Functions defined outside of your class definition can be defined after `main()` as shown below.

```
class Foo
{
    // member function prototype
    void func1(); 

    //member function definition inside class
    void func2()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from func2" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    foo instance;

    instance.func1();
    instance.func2();

    return 1;
}

void Foo::func1()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from func1" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.  They are all informative and helpful.  I voted all of them up, and marked the first as an answer because I can only mark one as an answer.  However, for future readers, I recommend that all these answers are worth reading.  They are certainly helpful to me.

Answer (score 2):

In a way, a function prototype is the function-equivalent of a complete class definition, not a forward declaration.

so, forward declaration:

```
class X;
```

introduces the name X and informs the compiler that it is a class. After seeing this, the compiler will allow you to hold and transfer references and pointers to an X, but not create or copy values (instances) of it, so:

```
void foo(X&); // is allowed (because it deals in references), but
void foo(X); // is not (it deals in copies of an X)
```

class definition:

```
class X { ... };
```

fully defines X's interface and storage requirements. After this, the compiler will allow you to do anything you like with an X. This is why the class definition generally goes into a header file.

function prototype involving forward-declared classes:

```
int foo(X&); // X may be forward-declared or defined
```

This has fully declared the complete shape and behaviour of calling foo(X&). The code at the call-site can be completely compiled.

function prototype involving defined classes:

```
int foo2(X); // X must be defined
```

This has fully declared the complete shape and behaviour of calling foo2(X), including the requirements for copying the X onto the stack (for emplacing it there when called with a temporary). The code at the call-site can be completely compiled.